# Two NavigationBar Items appears twice in the second current view

Tags: swiftui, uinavigationitem

I have a current SwiftUI View with a Navigation Bar item . I created a Back Button on this current view so that the title is not inherited from the previous view (NEWSview)  with list of news websites to navigate to the current view  and clicking on the back button returns me to the previous view. This is sample code of the previous view screen how i did:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            List (networkManager.posts) { post in
                NavigationLink (destination: DetailView(url: post.url) ) {
                    HStack {
                        Text(String(post.points))
                        Text(post.title)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("News")
            
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.networkManager.fetchData()
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

This is the current screen view that is having the two buttons:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    let url : String?
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var mode
    var body: some View {
        WebView(urlString: url)
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                                    Button(action: {
                                        self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                                    }, label: {
                                        HStack(spacing: 10) {
                                            Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                                                .resizable()
                                                .frame(width: 10.0, height: 19.0)
                                                .font(.headline)
                                            Text("Back")
                                            
                                        }
                                    })
            )
    }
}
```

Now the issue is : The current screen NavBar has two buttons like this : one with news title and the back button (Picture attached) [image]. I want only to remain with the Back Button on the current view that on click will navigate back to the previous root view . I thought what i did is right but missing something . If remove the entire code with the button in the current view , i will only see the "NEWS" navigation that on click will return me to the News View but i want a back title that should not be inherited from the news view .

Comment: You didn't post enough code to tell, but usually this is the work of having a NavigationView in the second view. Things get doubled.

Comment: Added some more details

Comment: use only one navigationView, only in first view (root view).

Comment: How then will i be able to change the title of the second view to "Back" Instead of "News"

Comment: @DerekKim did you figure out this problem?

Comment: @Luffy yaah thanks man for asking